# Replace system menu popup on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I want to replace the default sys menu(Restore, Move, Size etc.) with my custom entries. The menu I'm talking about can be opened either by clicking left button on window icon or by clicking right button on window title.
I can remove all the items and populate this menu with my own entries. But if I remove all entries then minimize, maximize and close buttons become inactive. So they depend on those menu items.

I want to have min, max, close buttons working as usual but system menu which contains my own items(like it is done in Windows Media Player).
I'm using Qt, but I'm almost sure it can't be done with it so any solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not remove Min/Max/Close items from system menu. It's much better to process [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message instead (`SC_MINIMIZE`, `SC_MAXIMIZE`, `SC_RESTORE`, `SC_CLOSE`).

Comment: If I don't remove those items from the menu then I can't have fully customized menu since it will contain entries I don't need.

Comment: You don't need "Close" item, or you need your own "Close" item? (same Q. to other min/max/restore/...)

Comment: Well, I need close(it will have other name though) but I don't need min, max etc. Still I do want to keep the button functional for min/max

Comment: Create you own popup menu (don't change system) and TrackPopupMenu on appropriate WM_NCxxx message (WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN/UP etc.)

Comment: Process corresponding events and you'll never see "sysmenu".

Comment: I've hooked WM_CONTEXTMENU and just showed my own menu instead of system. So I mark this as the answer.